# VLOOKUP across 2 worksheets for comma separated values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to do a vlookup using vba to look up each country per continent and return a true value on each column. For example, I get a true under Europe Lookup if Belgium is listed as one of the countries. See below for the current code I have. Issues I want to fix are:

First, I want to be able to lookup each country to confirm if they are in the countries tab. That way, I know if there is a new country I need to add. What I have currently looks up to check if at least one of the countries is listed but would like to make sure all countries are listed.[image]

Additionally, I want to make it automated such that if a new country is added to the countries list, I don't have to edit the macros.[image]

Also, is there a way to do the lookup for separate continents one at a time? Currently, it just returns a true if the country is in the list irrespective of the continents. I know this means I'll have separate lines of codes for each continent but that's fine.

```
Sub Macro1()

Sheets("Sales Table").Select
Range("D2").Select
Dim LastRowColumnD As Long
LastRowColumnD = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D2:D" & LastRowColumnD).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Countries'!R2C1:R11C1,RC[-2])))>0"

Range("E2").Select
Dim LastRowColumnE As Long
LastRowColumnE = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E2:E" & LastRowColumnE).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Countries'!R2C1:R11C1,RC[-3])))>0"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of output are you trying to get, but something like this may work for you and you'll need to adapt a little:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim Mydata As Variant
Dim WKData As Worksheet
Dim rngCountries As Range
Dim MyF As WorksheetFunction

Set MyF = WorksheetFunction

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Countries")
    LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngCountries = .Range("A2:B" & LR)
End With

Set WKData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Table")

With WKData
    LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Mydata = .Range("B2:B" & LR).Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Mydata) Step 1
        j = UBound(Split(Mydata(i, 1), ", "))
        'j = how many countries -1, so j+1= total countries in cell
        For k = 0 To j Step 1
            'we loop trough each country in cell
            If MyF.CountIfs(rngCountries.Columns(1), Split(Mydata(i, 1), ", ")(k), rngCountries.Columns(2), "Europe") <> 0 Then .Range("E" & (i + 1)).Value = .Range("E" & (i + 1)).Value + 1 'Europe Check
            If MyF.CountIfs(rngCountries.Columns(1), Split(Mydata(i, 1), ", ")(k), rngCountries.Columns(2), "Africa") <> 0 Then .Range("F" & (i + 1)).Value = .Range("F" & (i + 1)).Value + 1 'Africa Check
            If MyF.CountIfs(rngCountries.Columns(1), Split(Mydata(i, 1), ", ")(k), rngCountries.Columns(2), "Asia") <> 0 Then .Range("G" & (i + 1)).Value = .Range("G" & (i + 1)).Value + 1 'Asia Check
        Next k
        
        'check all countries: if the sum equals k+1, then all countries in cell are present
        .Range("D" & (i + 1)).Value = IIf(MyF.Sum(Range("E" & (i + 1) & ":G" & (i + 1))) = k, "YES", "NO")
    Next i
End With

'clean variables
Erase Mydata
Set MyF = Nothing
Set rngCountries = Nothing
Set WKData = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've used arrays and Splits to create arrays so you can loop trough each individual country:

[image]

Notice I added "Portugal" to check the "NO" value in the "All countries" column. Every NO means there is a country in that cell that is not present in your range of countries.

Comment: Thank you! This almost solved my problem.  The only other thing needed is that to have the lookup range automated within the code. For example, in your code, you had a defined range in the countries tab which was (A2:B11). Is there a way to have this automated so that I wouldn't have to edit the code if a new country was added/removed from the list?

Comment: @SammieDave Yes, get the last row of it with and assign it to the range. Check updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The CurrentRegion property of Range will catch countries added to the Countries tab.

You don't necessarily need a separate line of code for each continent.  If you keep a consistent column naming strategy, you can make the code flexible  enough to catch added continents.

```
Sub macroSplitter()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim salesSheet As Worksheet, Countries As Worksheet, continent As String
Dim j As Long
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set salesSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sales Table")
Set Countries = wb.Worksheets("Countries")

'Range.CurrentRegion selects a region contiguous with the designated cell
countryArray = Countries.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2

For Each cell In salesSheet.Range("B2", salesSheet.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    splitCell = Split(cell, ", ")
    For Each country In splitCell
        If inCountry(country, countryArray) Then
            continent = whichcontinent(country, countryArray)
            'using match to look for continent column, and End(xlToRight) to allow for additional continents to be added
            Cells(cell.Row, WorksheetFunction.Match(continent & " Lookup", salesSheet.Range("A1", salesSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)), 0)).Value2 = True
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = False
        End If
    Next
    If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = vbNullString Then cell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = True
    For j = WorksheetFunction.Match("Europe Lookup", salesSheet.Range("A1", salesSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)), 0) To salesSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        If Cells(cell.Row, j).Value2 = vbNullString Then Cells(cell.Row, j).Value2 = False
    Next
Next cell

End Sub
Private Function inCountry(c, arr) As Boolean
Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If c = arr(i, 1) Then inCountry = True
    Next
End Function
Private Function whichcontinent(c, arr) As String
Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If c = arr(i, 1) Then whichcontinent = arr(i, 2)
    Next
End Function
```